# Making fill colors match in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making multiple bar charts. I am using fill to color code based on the levels of a factor. The factor name is Percentile.Category and the levels are 0-25, 26-50, 51-75, 76-90, 91-100. The problem is that not all of the charts have all 5 levels of the factor, so when I use a color palette, the factors don't have the same colors in different charts.

This is an example of the code I have to generate a plot. I basically replicated the same thing with different data frames to produce multiple plots:

```
UC %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Provider.Name, Score), y = Score)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = Percentile.category)) +
  coord_flip() +
  ggtitle("Urgent Care Percentiles for 'Would Recommend Facility'") +
  ylab("Would You Recommend Top Box") +
  xlab("Provider") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Spectral") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Score), size = 2.5, vjust = .4, hjust = 1.2, fontface = "bold")
```

Right now, if a particular data frame is missing any data at one of the factor levels, the colors for each factor level change. What I want is for the factor level colors to match in the different plots. For example, 51-75 is the same color in all of them.

Comment: Not sure if there's another way of doing this, but I think you need to set manual scales to your plots? That will work.

Comment: set colors beforehand : `cols <- c("0-25" = "red", "26-50," = "pink", ...)` and add `scale_color_manual(values = cols)` if you run out of color ideas :  https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjg3Pap9PDjAhVO4YUKHb2_C0YQFjAAegQIAxAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stat.columbia.edu%2F~tzheng%2Ffiles%2FRcolor.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1XIn-mwZ73RgG8bxh4Lan4

Comment: Check the `drop` argument in  `scale_color_manual(values = c(...), drop=F)` and set it to `FALSE`

Comment: could you share a sample of the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that the variable you use as `fill` has the same levels in all the data frames. I would do the following using `dplyr` to transform the variables in advance:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
lvls <- c('0-25', '26-50', '51-75', '76-90', '91-100')
some_df %>%
  mutate(Score = factor(Score, levels = lvls)) %>%
  ggplot(<etc>) %>%
  <the rest of your code>
```

Comment: These suggestions helped me fix it!. I was able to set up the levels of the factor beforehand with the mutate function. It still didn't work when not all levels were in the data set, so I used the drop argument. Now it is working as I need it to.  Thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome! Please consider marking my answer as the solution and upvoting it so it can benefit others :)

Comment: I marked it as the solution. I just started on stack overflow (this is my first post), so my upvote will not be shown until I have at least 15 reputation points.